# How to prevent button from popping up?

Tags: java, css, swing, jbutton, accordion

I'm trying to make an accordion panel in my java swing browser.I added some buttons in the panel.
  Here is my code(I've removed some buttons from the code to make it smaller, if you face any problem understanding my code please let me know)

```
public class AccordianTest {

JPanel getContent() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.add(new AccordianPanel().getPanel(), gbc);
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    return panel;
}
}

class AccordianPanel extends JPanel {

boolean movingComponents = false;
int visibleIndex = 3;

public AccordianPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    int childCount = 4;
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    int h = 0;
    String[] name = {"Navigation", "Settings", "New tab", "More Tools"};
    for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
        ChildPanel child = new ChildPanel(j + 1, ml, name[j]);
        add(child);
        d = child.getPreferredSize();
        child.setBounds(0, h, d.width, d.height);
        if (j < childCount - 1) {
            h += ControlPanel.HEIGHT;
        }
    }
    h += d.height;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, h));
    // Set z-order for children.
    setZOrder();
}

private void setZOrder() {
    Component[] c = getComponents();
    for (int j = 0; j < c.length - 1; j++) {
        setComponentZOrder(c[j], c.length - 1 - j);
    }
}

private void setChildVisible(int indexToOpen) {
    int[] indices = new int[0];
    int travelLimit = 0;
    if (visibleIndex < indexToOpen) {
        travelLimit = ControlPanel.HEIGHT
                - getComponent(visibleIndex).getHeight();
        int n = indexToOpen - visibleIndex;
        indices = new int[n];
        for (int j = visibleIndex, k = 0; j < indexToOpen; j++, k++) {
            indices[k] = j + 1;
        }
    } else if (visibleIndex > indexToOpen) {
        travelLimit = getComponent(visibleIndex).getHeight()
                - ControlPanel.HEIGHT;
        int n = visibleIndex - indexToOpen;
        indices = new int[n];
        for (int j = indexToOpen, k = 0; j < visibleIndex; j++, k++) {
            indices[k] = j + 1;
        }
    }
    movePanels(indices, travelLimit);
    visibleIndex = indexToOpen;
}

private void movePanels(final int[] indices, final int travel) {
    movingComponents = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Component[] c = getComponents();
            int limit = travel > 0 ? travel : 0;
            int count = travel > 0 ? 0 : travel;
            int dy = travel > 0 ? 1 : -1;
            while (count < limit) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("interrupted");
                    break;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
                    int index = c.length - 1 - indices[j];
                    Point p = c[index].getLocation();
                    p.y += dy;
                    c[index].setLocation(p.x, p.y);
                }
                repaint();
                count++;
            }
            movingComponents = false;
        }
    });
    thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}

private MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int index = ((ControlPanel) e.getSource()).id - 1;
        if (!movingComponents) {
            setChildVisible(index);
        }
    }
};

public JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.add(this, gbc);
    return panel;
}
}

class ChildPanel extends JPanel {

public ChildPanel(int id, MouseListener ml, String name) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new ControlPanel(id, ml, name), "First");
    add(getContent(id));
}

private JPanel getContent(int id) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.anchor = gbc.PAGE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    if (id == 1) {
        JButton hbutton = new JButton("Home");
        hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_1rsz_house.png")));
        hbutton.setToolTipText("Click to go home");
        hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
        hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
        panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
        JButton hisbutton = new JButton("History");
        hisbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_1rsz_25011.png")));
        hisbutton.setToolTipText("Browse previous pages");
        hisbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
        hisbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(hisbutton, gbc);

    }
    else if (id == 2) {
        gbc.anchor = gbc.PAGE_START;
        JButton zbutton = new JButton("Zoom");
        zbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_rsz_2fontsize.png")));
        zbutton.setToolTipText("Click to get better view");
        zbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 15));
        zbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
        panel.add(zbutton, gbc);
        JSlider slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(slider,gbc);
    }
    else if (id==3)
    {
        JButton hbutton = new JButton("New Page");
        hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_download_4.jpg")));
        hbutton.setToolTipText("Start with new page");
        hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
        hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
        panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
    }
    else {
         JButton hbutton = new JButton("Copy");
        hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_file_copy.png")));
        hbutton.setToolTipText("Copy");
        hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
        hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
        panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
    }
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    return panel;
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(150, 150);
}
}

class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

int id;
JLabel titleLabel;
Color c1 = new Color(51,3,0);
Color c2 = new Color(153, 129, 127);
Color fontFg = Color.BLACK;
Color rolloverFg = new Color(206, 157, 157);
public final static int HEIGHT = 40;

public ControlPanel(int id, MouseListener ml, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(titleLabel = new JLabel(name));
    titleLabel.setForeground(fontFg);
    Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
    d.height = HEIGHT;
    setPreferredSize(d);
    addMouseListener(ml);
    addMouseListener(listener);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int w = getWidth();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(w / 2, 0, c1, w / 2, HEIGHT / 2, c2));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, HEIGHT);
}

private MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        titleLabel.setForeground(rolloverFg);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        titleLabel.setForeground(fontFg);
    }
};
}
```

But when i run my browser the button which should remain hidden under panel shows up on the button of another panel

[image]
[image]

here "History" of the first panel "Navigation" shows up when i click on second panel "Settings" and hides "Zoom" button of 2nd panel. What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to override the [JComponent#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#isOptimizedDrawingEnabled--) method of `AccordianPanel` to return false:

```
class AccordianPanel extends JPanel {
  boolean movingComponents = false;
  int visibleIndex = 3;
  public AccordianPanel() {
    //...
  }
  @Override public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AccordianTest2 {
  JPanel getContent() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.add(new AccordianPanel().getPanel(), gbc);
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    return panel;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new AccordianTest2().getContent());
      f.setSize(320, 480);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}

class AccordianPanel extends JPanel {
  boolean movingComponents = false;
  int visibleIndex = 3;

  public AccordianPanel() {
    setLayout(null);
    int childCount = 4;
    Dimension d = new Dimension();
    int h = 0;
    String[] name = {"Navigation", "Settings", "New tab", "More Tools"};
    for (int j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {
      ChildPanel child = new ChildPanel(j + 1, ml, name[j]);
      add(child);
      d = child.getPreferredSize();
      child.setBounds(0, h, d.width, d.height);
      if (j < childCount - 1) {
        h += ControlPanel.HEIGHT;
      }
    }
    h += d.height;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(d.width, h));
    // Set z-order for children.
    setZOrder();
  }
  @Override public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
  private void setZOrder() {
    Component[] c = getComponents();
    for (int j = 0; j < c.length - 1; j++) {
      setComponentZOrder(c[j], c.length - 1 - j);
    }
  }

  private void setChildVisible(int indexToOpen) {
    int[] indices = new int[0];
    int travelLimit = 0;
    if (visibleIndex < indexToOpen) {
      travelLimit = ControlPanel.HEIGHT
                    - getComponent(visibleIndex).getHeight();
      int n = indexToOpen - visibleIndex;
      indices = new int[n];
      for (int j = visibleIndex, k = 0; j < indexToOpen; j++, k++) {
        indices[k] = j + 1;
      }
    } else if (visibleIndex > indexToOpen) {
      travelLimit = getComponent(visibleIndex).getHeight()
                    - ControlPanel.HEIGHT;
      int n = visibleIndex - indexToOpen;
      indices = new int[n];
      for (int j = indexToOpen, k = 0; j < visibleIndex; j++, k++) {
        indices[k] = j + 1;
      }
    }
    movePanels(indices, travelLimit);
    visibleIndex = indexToOpen;
  }

  private void movePanels(final int[] indices, final int travel) {
    movingComponents = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        Component[] c = getComponents();
        int limit = travel > 0 ? travel : 0;
        int dy = travel > 0 ? 1 : -1;

        (new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
          @Override public Void doInBackground() {
            int count = travel > 0 ? 0 : travel;
            while (count < limit) {
              try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
                break;
              }
              for (int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
                int index = c.length - 1 - indices[j];
                Point p = c[index].getLocation();
                p.y += dy;
                c[index].setLocation(p.x, p.y);
              }
              publish(count++);
            }
            return null;
          }
          @Override protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            repaint();
          }
          @Override public void done() {
            movingComponents = false;
          }
        }).execute();
//         while (count < limit) {
//           try {
//             Thread.sleep(5);
//           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//             System.out.println("interrupted");
//             break;
//           }
//           for (int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
//             int index = c.length - 1 - indices[j];
//             Point p = c[index].getLocation();
//             p.y += dy;
//             c[index].setLocation(p.x, p.y);
//           }
//           repaint();
//           count++;
//         }
//         movingComponents = false;
      }
    });
    thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
  }

  private MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      int index = ((ControlPanel) e.getSource()).id - 1;
      if (!movingComponents) {
        setChildVisible(index);
      }
    }
  };

  public JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel.add(this, gbc);
    return panel;
  }
}

class ChildPanel extends JPanel {

  public ChildPanel(int id, MouseListener ml, String name) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new ControlPanel(id, ml, name), "First");
    add(getContent(id));
  }

  private JPanel getContent(int id) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weighty = 0;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.anchor = gbc.PAGE_START;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    if (id == 1) {
      JButton hbutton = new JButton("Home");
      //hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_1rsz_house.png")));
      hbutton.setToolTipText("Click to go home");
      hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
      hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
      panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
      JButton hisbutton = new JButton("History");
      //hisbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_1rsz_25011.png")));
      hisbutton.setToolTipText("Browse previous pages");
      hisbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
      hisbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
      gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.weightx = 0.0;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 1;
      panel.add(hisbutton, gbc);

    } else if (id == 2) {
      gbc.anchor = gbc.PAGE_START;
      JButton zbutton = new JButton("Zoom");
      //zbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_rsz_2fontsize.png")));
      zbutton.setToolTipText("Click to get better view");
      zbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 15));
      zbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
      panel.add(zbutton, gbc);
      JSlider slider = new JSlider();
      slider.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.weightx = 0.0;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 1;
      panel.add(slider, gbc);
    } else if (id == 3) {
      JButton hbutton = new JButton("New Page");
      //hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_download_4.jpg")));
      hbutton.setToolTipText("Start with new page");
      hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
      hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
      panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
    } else {
      JButton hbutton = new JButton("Copy");
      //hbutton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/rsz_file_copy.png")));
      hbutton.setToolTipText("Copy");
      hbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 25));
      hbutton.setBackground(Color.decode("#B29A99"));
      panel.add(hbutton, gbc);
    }
    panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    return panel;
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(150, 150);
  }
}

class ControlPanel extends JPanel {

  int id;
  JLabel titleLabel;
  Color c1 = new Color(51, 3, 0);
  Color c2 = new Color(153, 129, 127);
  Color fontFg = Color.BLACK;
  Color rolloverFg = new Color(206, 157, 157);
  public final static int HEIGHT = 40;

  public ControlPanel(int id, MouseListener ml, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(titleLabel = new JLabel(name));
    titleLabel.setForeground(fontFg);
    Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
    d.height = HEIGHT;
    setPreferredSize(d);
    addMouseListener(ml);
    addMouseListener(listener);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    int w = getWidth();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(w / 2, 0, c1, w / 2, HEIGHT / 2, c2));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, w, HEIGHT);
  }

  private MouseListener listener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      titleLabel.setForeground(rolloverFg);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
      titleLabel.setForeground(fontFg);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but i'm using it another class so this class don't have any main function in my program, can you please tell me how can i use it without it's main class (for using it in another class) ?